# eTapestry API: updating multi select value

Tags: php, api, nusoap

Can someone help me with eTapestry API. I'm using applyDefinedValues Method . Documentation is here: https://www.blackbaudhq.com/files/etapestry/api/methods/applyDefinedValues.html

Everything works fine when updating fields that are defined as text, int or other values, but I don't know how to update multiselect type.

I tried to send data like this:

```
$dv1["value"] = array('Eclipses','Electional','Estoteric/Spritual/Occult');
```

but system updates as new value 'Array'?

eTapestry return values looks like this:

```
[18] => Array
            (
                [dataType] => 0
                [displayType] => 2
                [fieldName] => My Interests
                [fieldRef] => 249.0.39428157
                [value] => Electional
                [valueRef] => 249.0.39782431
            )

        [19] => Array
            (
                [dataType] => 0
                [displayType] => 2
                [fieldName] => My Interests
                [fieldRef] => 249.0.39428157
                [value] => Estoteric/Spritual/Occult
                [valueRef] => 249.0.39782420
            )

        ........

        [21] => Array
            (
                [dataType] => 0
                [displayType] => 2
                [fieldName] => My Interests
                [fieldRef] => 249.0.39428157
                [value] => Archetypal Cosmology
                [valueRef] => 249.0.39782417
```